# Matlab quitting if high number of recursions?

Tags: matlab, recursion

I have a problem with the number of recursions in Matlab: if I set a number of recursions greater than 10^3 (say 10^4) then Matlab (R2015a) quits. Why?

Here's my code

```
max_rec=10^4; %maximum number of recursions allowed
set(0,'RecursionLimit',max_rec+10);
XY=[0.3 0.4]
t=Invert(XY(1),XY(2),max_rec);
```

where

```
function t=Invert(x1,x2,iter)
t = 0;
if iter > 0
      if x1<0.5
         if x2<0.5
            t=(0+Invert(2*x2, 2*x1, iter-1))/4;
         else
            t=(1+Invert(2*x1, 2*x2-1, iter-1))/4;
         end
      else
        if x2>=0.5
           t=(2+Invert(2*x1-1, 2*x2-1, iter-1))/4;
        else
           t=(3+Invert(1-2*x2, 2-2*x1, iter-1))/4;
        end
      end     
end
end
```

Comment: MATLAB explicitly tells you: `Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer.`

Comment: Is there a way to increase the stack space?

Comment: The bigger question is, what are you trying to accomplish? Do you really need to use a recursive approach?